# Visual Studio 2010 MFC dialogs: Aero style?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-7, mfc

Currently, my MFC dialog looks like from Windows 98. Is there a way to make it use the active Windows 7 style (aero)?

(I'm using C++)

Answer (score 16):

Try adding this to Stdafx.h

```
#ifdef _UNICODE
#if defined _M_IX86
#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='x86' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
#elif defined _M_IA64
#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='ia64' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
#elif defined _M_X64
#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='amd64' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
#else
#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
#endif
#endif
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a good solution, now I can avoid all the hassle of creating and embedding the manifest. Just tested on a Win32 application and it works as expected.

Comment: I know I am two years late, but this still applies in MFC applications. Cheers for the tip.

Comment: Is there any hope for projects  using multibyte charsets instead of unicode? I haven't set _UNICODE.

Comment: Hi @masche - based on [this forum post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.vc.mfc/NmGfnLLI2EI), it looks like there are problems with the v6 common controls in multibyte apps. Someone mentions an issue in the edit control or maybe `CEditView`. Others down thread say they didn't have any issues. You could try commenting out the `_UNICODE` ifdef and test it out I suppose.

Answer (score 3):

You need a manifest in your application with a theme and ensure you do a InitCommonControlsEx().

Also have a look at the MFC feature pack too, also below is a link to examples too:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982451.aspx
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista/VGGlassIntro.aspx
- http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/vcsamplesmfc
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista/VGGlassIntro.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add a valid manifest to your application.

Comment: I have already enabled the manifest generation in the properties (it was by default)

Comment: Just because the manifest is generated doesn't mean it is specifying Common Controls 6. Open your (non-themed) EXE in Visual Studio's Object Browser via File > Open and view inspect the current manifest in its resources.