# How to create (curve edged/Round Rectangle) mfc buttons, text box and combo box?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, mfc-feature-pack

I am new to MFC, need to change the existing design of our legacy MFC app. unlike the standard MFC sharp edged buttons, text box etc. I need curve edged design for the whole app. please suggest if there is any way I can achieve this.

Curve edges as shown in the image, so far I couldn't achieve this. Please let me know if it is possible or not through MFC. It is not possible with BCGSoft also  [image: Screenshot]

[image: left is current, right is the required UI]

Comment: Yes, that's possible. No, it's not easily possible. You'll be writing **a lot** of code. And you need to know MFC inside and out. And Windows API programming.

Comment: I don't see any curved edges in the controls shown in the pic, they are the standard "flat" controls of the last Windows versions. What do you mean and what do you want exactly? Try setting the toolkit version in the build options, you can achieve an "old" look, though I'm not sure about its acceptance.

Comment: @con The edit controls have rounded corners with fairly small corner radii. Those aren't sharp edges as used by the standard edit control (though I have not checked how they look in Windows 11).

Comment: @ConstantineGeorgiou I have updated the current and required UI, the difference is the older ones look outdated as per the MFC standards. my doubt is if i can achieve the new look with MFC.

Comment: See [Enabling Visual Styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/cookbook-overview) on how to use the common controls library version 6. No rounded corners there either, but those have the familiar look of the "new" controls introduced with Windows Vista (I believe).

Comment: @IInspectable it was introduced with XP already.

Comment: Thanks for all your valuable comments, i got some progress with the attached link. Enabling Visual Styles was really helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979802/visual-studio-2010-mfc-dialogs-aero-style

Comment: My two cents: Use `CMFCButton` instead of `CButton`. It  gives you a little more control over its appearance.

Comment: I think you should look into NM_CUSTOMDRAW notification code sent to a parent window (dialog). Visual styles should be enabled. 
Try https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/nm-customdraw-button to start with.